# compare dates within ng-if angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I am looking to compare two dates in ng-if this is what my jade file looks like.

html :

```
<button ng-if="{{product.experationDate}} < {{CurrentDate}}" type="button> 
// do somthing
</button>
```

javascript :

```
$scope.CurrentDate = new Date();
```

and :   `date_expiration: {type: Date}`

but it not work ! 
any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Use `ng-if="(product.experationDate < CurrentDate)"` instead

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this kind of logic in the template. That's what your services and controllers are for. You need to have a method in your controller that returns the boolean:

```
isExpirationExpired(product) {
  // your date logic here, recommend moment.js;
  return moment(product.experationDate).isBefore(moment(currentdate));
  // or without using moment.js:
  return product.experationDate.getTime() < currentdate.getTime();
  // or using Date
  return new Date(product.experationDate).valueOf() < new Date(currentdate).valueOf();
}
```

And your template:

```
ng-if="vm.isExpirationExpired(product)"
```

Comment: Totally agree with that. :)

Comment: he is not using moment.. Please answer in context.

Comment: Yes that's why I put the comment 'recommend moment.js'

Comment: If I would ask a question on SO - i would be glad that people point out better approaches then the ons i'm currently having... +1 @rrd

Comment: I've updated the answer to include other possibilities, although he may have to play around with them since I don't know the format of product.experationDate or currentDate

Comment: Isn't it recommended to not use methods in angular templates like this because they will get called anytime any change occurs?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

`<button ng-if="product.experationDate < CurrentDate" type="button> 
// do somthing
</button>`

In Angular directives like ng-if, you don't need the {{ }} as the expression is evaluate either way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can compare javascript date type directly.
Instead, do this and remove {{}}

```
<button ng-if="product.experationDate.getTime() < CurrentDate.getTime()" type="button> 
// do somthing
</button>
```

which compares their milliseconds.

Comment: i try that but  "product.experationDate.getTime()" does not output any thing. why ?  however   "CurrentDate.getTime()"  output somthing like these 15428745

Comment: both experationDate and CurrentDate are Date Type

Comment: how did you get experationDate? in a promise?